# For all $n$ there exists $x$ such that $\varphi(x)<\varphi(x+1)<\ldots<\varphi(x+n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

Let $\varphi$ be the Euler's function, i.e. $\varphi(n)$ stands for the number of integers $m \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Let $n\ge 2$ be a positive integer. Show that there exists infinitely many $x$ for which
$$
\varphi(x)<\varphi(x+1)<\ldots<\varphi(x+n).
$$

[It is a generalization of a math contest asking the same question for $n=2$; I know the answer, and it is positive]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that it's true?

Comment: Which contest? You may help us answering the general case by providing a link to the solution of that contest problem.

Comment: @barto I will search for the original source (in the case $n=2$), I just wrote it here recalling old memories..

Comment: Are you saying you have a proof of this statement? If so, you should (have) mention(ed) that in the question.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: The difference is that very few people are going to try to prove such a thing if they have no reason to believe that it's true.

Comment: In fact it's known that for any vector of positive reals $[c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n]$ you can find $x$ such that each ratio $\varphi(x+i)/\varphi(x)$ is arbitrarily close to $c_i$.  So one can prescribe any ordering among $\varphi(x), \ldots, \varphi(x+n)$ that one cares to wish for (indeed, on a set of positive density).

Comment: I agree this would solve the question, but how do you prove it?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti You seem to be sending mixed signals: in the question you say you know the answer is positive, and in one comment you assert that the lower asymptotic density is positive.  But here you ask how to prove it.  Do you already have a reference for the result?  If so, then what exactly are you looking for?  If not, then how do you know it's true?

Comment: Yes i know it s true because i know the exact reference for the general result. In any case, it s an interesting problem in my opinion, which can be solved by elementary techniques.. Then why don't ask it here, helping the reader saying that it admits for sure an elementary solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following $p$ will always denote a prime numer. $p_k$ will be the $k$-th prime.
Clearly it suffices to show that, given $0\le x_i<y_i\le\alpha$ ($i=0,\dots,n$), we can always find $x$ s.t. $\phi(x+i)\in(x_i,y_i)$ for any $i$.
Here $\alpha:=\prod_{p\le n+1}\frac{p-1}{p}$.

We first prove this crucial lemma, which in particular gives the thesis for $n=0$:

**Lemma.** Given $0\le x<y\le 1$ and any $z\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a set $A$ of primes $>z$ s.t. $m:=\prod_{p\in A}p$ satisfies $x<\frac{\phi(m)}{m}<y$. 
We remember that $\frac{\phi(m)}{m}=\prod_{p\in A}\frac{p-1}{p}$. 
*Proof.* Pick any prime $p_k>z$ s.t. $\frac{p_k-1}{p_k}>x$. Since $\prod_p\frac{p-1}{p}=0$ (which follows from the well-known divergence of $\sum_p\frac{1}{p}$) there exists a *maximal* $\ell\ge k$ s.t. $\prod_{j=k}^\ell\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}>x$. Put all the primes $p_k,\dots,p_\ell$ in the set $A$
and look for another $k'>\ell$ s.t. $\left(\prod_{j=k}^\ell\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}\right)\frac{p_{k'}-1}{p_{k'}}>x$ and again
there is a maximal $\ell'\ge k'$ for which
$$\left(\prod_{j=k}^\ell\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}\right)\left(\prod_{j=k'}^{\ell'}\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}\right)>x$$
holds. Add $p_{k'},\dots,p_{\ell'}$ to $A$ and iterate this procedure. After a finite number of steps we will obtain the desired $A$ since
$\frac{p-1}{p}\to 1$ as $p\to\infty$ (so if a positive real number $t$ is such that $t>x$ and $t\frac{p-1}{p}\le x$, for some large $p$,
we will have $t<y$). $\blacksquare$

Set $q:=\prod_{p\le n+1}q$. Applying the lemma $n+1$ times, we find disjoint sets $A_0,\dots,A_n$ of primes $>n+1$ such that, calling $s_i:=\prod_{p\in A_i}p$,
we have $x_i\frac{(q,i)}{\phi((q,i))}<\frac{\phi(s_i)}{s_i}<y_i\frac{(q,i)}{\phi((q,i))}$. Here $(q,i)=\text{gcd}(q,i)$.
This can be done since $\frac{(q,i)}{\phi((q,i))}\le\frac{1}{\alpha}$, while $x_i,y_i\le \alpha$. The reason for this choice of the intervals will be apparent in a moment.

Now let $M$ be very large and call $B$ the set of primes $p_j>n+1$ with $j\le M$ which do not belong to any $A_i$, i.e.
$$B:=\{p_j\mid j\le M\}\setminus\left(\{1,\dots,n+1\}\cup\bigcup_{i=0}^n A_i\right),$$
and set $b:=\prod_{p\in B}p$.
The Chinese Remainder Theorem allows us to solve this system of congruences:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv 0\pmod{qs_0} \\ x+i\equiv 0\pmod{s_i}\ \forall i=1,\dots,n \\ x-1\equiv 0\pmod{b}\end{cases}$$
We claim that, for $M$ big enough, the smallest positive solution $x$ of this system is the one we are looking for.
In fact, if $p\mid x+i$ (for any $i=0,\dots,n$), then there are three cases:

- $p\le n+1$
- $p\in A_i$
- $p=p_j$ for some $j>M$.

There are no other possibilities (otherwise $p\in A_{i'}$ for some $i'\neq i$ or $p\in B$; so $p\mid x+i'$ or $p\mid x-1$ but none of these is possible,
as $p$ would then divide a number $\le n+1$).
Notice that for the first two cases the suitable converse holds, i.e. every prime in $A_i$ divides $x+i$, while every prime $p\le n+1$ divides $x+i$ iff $p\mid i$, thanks to the fact that $p\mid q\mid x$.

Thus $$\frac{\phi(x+i)}{x+i}=\prod_{p\mid (q,i)}\frac{p-1}{p}\prod_{p\in A_i}\frac{p-1}{p}\prod_{p_j\mid x+i,\ j>M}\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}$$
and $\prod_{p\mid (q,i)}\frac{p-1}{p}=\frac{\phi((q,i))}{(q,i)}$, so by the estimates satisfied by $s_i$ we get
$$\prod_{p\mid (q,i)}\frac{p-1}{p}\prod_{p\in A_i}\frac{p-1}{p}=\frac{\phi((q,i))}{(q,i)}s_i\in(x_i,y_i).$$
To conclude we just have to show that the last product tends to $1$ as $M\to \infty$. But by minimality $x<\prod_{j=1}^M p_j$, so
(for $M$ large) $x+i<\prod_{j=1}^{M+1} p_j$, thus $x+i$ has at most $M$ distinct prime factors.
So
$$1\ge \prod_{p_j\mid x+i,\ j>M}\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}=\prod_{p_j\mid x+i,\ j>M}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\ge\left(1-\frac{1}{p_M}\right)^M$$
and hence
$$\liminf_{M\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_M}\right)^M\ge\liminf_{M\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{aM}\right)^M=e^{-\frac{1}{a}}$$
for any $a>0$, where we used the very loose estimate $p_M\ge aM$ (for $M$ big enough depending on $a$). Sending $a\to\infty$ we get
$\liminf_{M\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_M}\right)^M\ge 1$, which gives $\lim_{M\to\infty}\prod_{p_j\mid x+i,\ j>M}\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}=1$ (note that $x$ depends on $M$!).

This also shows the result mentioned by Erick Wong in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for finishing this off!

Comment: Well, good job :P

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: do you know different solutions? As the comments to the question suggest, it seems that it already appeared somewhere in the literature..

Comment: Here is "my" proof (it is taken from an article of Greg Martin, which you can find on Arxiv) https://leonettipaolo.wordpress.com/fnfn1fn2-for-infinitely-many-n/

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:** We impose suitable divisibility conditions by performing the following algorithm:

1. Assign $a_k\leftarrow\frac{\phi(k)}{k}$ for $1\le k\le n+1$. Let $N\leftarrow n+1$. Let $S\leftarrow(n+1)\mathbb N$
2. If $a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_n$, terminate.
3. Let $i$ be maximal with $a_i\ge a_{i+1}$.
4. Let $p$ be the smallest prime $>N$.
5. Let $a_i\leftarrow a_i\cdot\left(1-\frac1p\right)$, $S\leftarrow S\cap\left(p\mathbb Z-i\right)$, $N\leftarrow p$ and go back to step 2.

The algorithm is guaranteed to terminate because $\prod\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ diverges to $0$.
Once it terminates, we have the following situation:
For $1\le i\le n$ and $p$ prime $\le N$, either $p\mid s+i$ for all $s\in S$ or $p\nmid s+i$ for all $s\in S$. In fact we obtain 
$$ \frac{\phi(s+i)}{s+i}=a_i\prod_{p|s+i\atop p>N}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$
for all $s\in S$ (this condition holds whenever we enter step 2).
This allows us to conclude $\phi(s+1)<\phi(s+2)<\ldots<\phi(s+n+1)$ provided that $\prod_{p|s+i\atop p>N}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ is always sufficiently close to $1$.
The question is: Can we achieve this?

Comment: Just a remark: For $n=2$, my algorithm produces $S=37182144+111546435\mathbb Z$,which is subobtimal. For $n=3$, the modulus is $\approx 8\cdot 10^{147}$, for $n=4$, $\approx 10^{297}$. It may often be "better" to skip a prime by just letting $S\leftarrow S\cap p\mathbb Z$. Or in step 3 to find $1\le i<j\le n+1$ that maximize $a_i/a_j$ ...

Comment: "suboptimal" is a bit of an understatement --- for $n=2$, I believe the first example is $\phi(315)=144$, $\phi(316)=156$, $\phi(317)=316$. But it's to be expected that a method that works in general finds only a very thin set of examples.

Comment: It depends what you mean with "tiny": letting $X$ be the set of solutions then the lower asymptotic density of $X$ is positive..